# Online status with service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, service-worker

Can I use service worker to obtain online status of user?

Not only if user logged in my site and doing some things.. If user turned on his computer and opened the browser.

I hope service worker can react on browser start and send requests to my server periodically but I can't find such event/way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, the [Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) may be an answer to your needs, but probably you'd need `periodicsync` mentioned in *The future* section of the article:

> We’re aiming to ship background sync to a stable version of Chrome in the first half of 2016. But we’re also working on a variant, “periodic background sync”. This will allow you to request a “periodicsync” event restricted by time interval, battery state and network state.

As for today, Background Sync API, according to [IsServiceWorkerReady](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/) is shipped in Chrome Stable.

Service worker can also react to `push` event - maybe it'll be sufficient for you?

Comment: As I understand, this feature if for delayed request until online. Sending request in offline will delay this request until you become online. And I want - when user start browser, service worker send me request, and periodically send me requests if browser started

Comment: Backgound sync requires user to go to site where I can execute reg.sync.register('tag-name') to my service worker do job

Comment: If user opens my site I know he is online without any service workers

Comment: @DmitryTeplyakov: service worker is event-driven, and currently functional events of service worker that can be handled are: `fetch`, `sync` and `push`. So: it's not possible.